# How can I delegate to a member in Scala?

Tags: scala, proxy

Is it possible in Scala to write something like:

```
trait Road {
  ...
}

class BridgeCauseway extends Road {
  // implements method in Road
}

class Bridge extends Road {
  val roadway = new BridgeCauseway()

  // delegate all Bridge methods to the `roadway` member
}
```

or do I need to implement each of `Road`'s methods, one by one, and call the corresponding method on `roadway`?

Comment: See Kevin Wright's auto-proxy compiler plugin.

Comment: @daniel - Interesting you should say that, I've recently fired that one back up again. The 2.9 compiler has changes in that seem able to support my original design.

Comment: @kevin - great! i think everyone needs this proxy functionality. it should definitely be a standard feature of scala! i'm writing forwarders all the time, the reason why i'm so lazy installing the compiler-plugin is exactly that - i need to install it and then convince sbt, idea etc. pp to transparently use it. does it work with the presentation compiler (e.g. in idea)?

Comment: I just pushed an update to GitHub, it's all in SBT against Scala 2.9.0.RC1 now.  Expect better documentation and examples within 24 hours.

Comment: @Kevin Wright That's so awesome - thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is with an implicit conversion instead of a class extension:

```
class Bridge { ... }
implicit def bridge2road(b: Bridge) = b.roadway
```

as long as you don't need the original `Bridge` to be carried along for the ride (e.g. you're going to store `Bridge` in a collection of `Road`).

If you do need to get the `Bridge` back again, you can add an `owner` method in `Road` which returns an `Any`, set it using a constructor parameter for `BridgeCauseway`, and then pattern-match to get your bridge:

```
trait Road {
  def owner: Any
  ...
}

class BridgeCauseway(val owner: Bridge) extends Road { . . . }

class Bridge extends Road {
  val roadway = new BridgeCauseway(this)
  ...
}

myBridgeCauseway.owner match {
  case b: Bridge => // Do bridge-specific stuff
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the implicit inside `Bridge`'s object companion? That will ensure an auto-forward. Of course, if the methods are side-effectful, it might not work as desired.

Comment: @Daniel - I didn't because there wasn't a companion.  But I agree, putting the implicit inside `object Bridge { ... }` is normally what one would want.

Comment: I know an implicit can replace child with child.parent, but is there any way to use implicits to replace child with child.parent.parent?

Comment: @MichaelLafayette - You'd need to give an example of what you want to do, given that your first statement is not strictly correct.  An implicit can replace anything with anything, and there is no special access for parent types.  It's inheritance that replaces child with child.parent!

Answer (score 3):

*If* you can make `Bridge` a `trait` you'll be sorted.

```
scala> trait A {
     |   val x: String
     | }
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A {
     |   val x = "foo"
     |   val y = "bar"
     | }
defined class B

scala> trait C extends A { self: B =>         
     |   val z = "baz"               
     | }
defined trait C

scala> new B with C
res51: B with C = $anon$1@1b4e829

scala> res51.x
res52: java.lang.String = foo

scala> res51.y
res53: java.lang.String = bar

scala> res51.z
res54: java.lang.String = baz
```