# How to make fully functional immutable classes in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, copy, prototype

I noticed that Scala has case classes. These appear to be for pattern matching, but I like that I can do this with them:

```
val bankAccount1 = new BankAccount("Daniel", 100)
val bankAccount2 = bankAccount1.copy(funds = 200)
```

Now "Daniel" has two bank accounts, one with $100 and one with $200. But when things get more complicated, `BankAccount` needs to be sub-classed and this doesn't work because case classes can't extend other case classes.

I want immutable classes than can be extended into more immutable classes. Like I want to be able to extend `BankAccount` to have immutable sub-classes `SavingsBankAccount` and `CheckingBankAccount`. I'm not sure if at this point I need to extend/implement the `Clonable` interface or define custom copy methods or something like that. I don't want to have to put too much boilerplate in the classes.

(If possible), how do I make immutable classes in Scala that can be copied and sub-classed and that aren't overly messy or verbose?

Comment: The problem with inheriting from functional, immutable classes is that they are then no longer (guaranteed to be) functional, immutable, since the subclass could override one of the methods to have a side-effect. Trying to solve this with static type checking is tricky, and basically equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: This is how I basically got around that: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=XeNptFcekSA . I made an implicit message forwarding function and made the subclass have a parameter named "parent" that forwards to the superclass. The superclass itself just contains data and then I added on traits for functionality. How cool is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the idiomatic way of doing that in Scala would be using encapsulation instead of inheritance. For instance you could have:

```
case class BankAccount(id: AccountId, customer: Customer)
case class SavingsBankAccount(account: BankAccount, line: SavingsLine)
```

This way you would keep the good properties of immutability and automatic apply, unapply, equals, hashCode and copy method generation.

However if you really wanted to use inheritance you have no other choice than to roll out your own custom solution. For instance implementing a trait `SubclassableCaseClass` which implements helper methods for a quick definition of the methods case classes give you for free.

Comment: Encapsulation appears to be a much better solution. Very clean to read and write and doesn't require mass refactoring or excess boilerplate.

Comment: Does Scala have a way to Proxy all of the public methods and variables in account: BankAccount into "SavingsBankAccount"? Like could I just make BankAccount extend Proxy or something like that?

Comment: I got it. I can just use the implicit keyword to delegate SavingsBankAccount.account to the SavingsBankAccount class. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477096/how-can-i-delegate-to-a-member-in-scala

Comment: Yes you can use an implicit conversion to operate on a `SavingsBankAccount` as if it is a `BankAccount`. However try and not to overuse this paradigm. As much as implicit conversions are useful and really handy, they can make code difficult to understand if used too much, especially to new team members studying the codebase for the first time.

Comment: This might be silly, but I ended up making everything that has a Parent subclass a generic abstract class called "Child" and then made those Child classes forward to a parameter in Child called Child.parent. Traits could be used for methods that need overriding. Sort of messy, but like this: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=XeNptFcekSA

Comment: Is there any way to make implicit replace something with an object contained within one of its objects? Like if I wanted to replace child with child.parent.parent?

Comment: To do this kind of nested modification a useful abstraction are lenses. Scalaz provides an implementation. You can take read a little bit about it here: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html

Answer (score 0):

Think if your `BankAccount` really needs to be concrete.

Can I have a BankAccount that is not of the type Savings or Checking?

If the answer to this question is no (in this example I guess it is), you could use a abstract class or...

**traits** !

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/126

When you don't really need hierarchies, you can do a lot with traits. Actually traits are better than abstract classes since you can have composability.

I found out programming in scala that most of the time you don't need to extend concrete objects, specially classes that just pack data.

If you really need `BankAccount` to be concrete, that I guess you are left with what you already suggested. :(

Comment: This is a very ugly solution because it does not allow me to deal with the code that is already in place without changing concrete objects intro traits and then refactoring everything.

Comment: Updated answer. Sorry if this doesn't solve your problem :(. What I saw from your example, BankAccount lead me to think that that was probably a abstract class/trait.  I didn't know your refactoring code. But trust me, in Java we are used to rely a lot of extension of concrete objects. Nowadays I rarely use it in scala.

Comment: Just one thing: Couldn't a abstract class solve your problem (without much refactoring?)

Comment: I didn't know you were refactoring :(, sorry. But try to follow this when writing new code. Not being able to extend case classes annoyed me, but now I rarely need it .